# Spring annotation and lifecycle.

Tags: java, spring

I have 2 questions specific to Spring.

1. Does @Component, @Service have to be on the implementation or interface ? And which one is the preferred method ?
2. If there is an external configuration class I have for e.g. ApplicationConfiguration. How do I hook this class into the Spring lifecycle ? What is the point I should look for ?

Comment: Are you referring to Java Bean Configuration in your second question. Then refer to http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/your-next-java-web-app-less-xml-no-long-restarts-fewer-hassles-part-1/#!/

Answer (score 1):

1. It should be on the implementation.
2. You should have text `.properties` file for your configuration.